# JSON structure output

Tags: json, node.js

I'm working on a school assignment, Node.js, and have trouble with getting my output correct. It's the `res.end` part that isn't working, but `res.end(stdout);` works. Why?

```
case "/status":
    /**
     * Run child process "uname -a".
     */
    cp.exec("uname -a", (error, stdout, stderr) => {
        if (error || stderr) {
            // Do something with the error(s)
            console.log("Something went wrong...", error, stderr);
        }

        // status route
        res.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "application/json" });
        res.end({
            "uname": stdout
        });
    });
break;
```

Comment: @JoeClay, send is not a function in non-Express.js.

Comment: Oops, I'm so used to using Express that I didn't realize, my apologies! The answer may still be similar, however - I'll write one up and post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As specified in the [Node.js docs](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_end_data_encoding_callback), `res.end` can only take a string or a buffer - or nothing at all - as its first parameter. If you wish to send JSON using it, you'll have to set the content type (which you've done) and stringify the object:

```
res.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "application/json" });
res.end(JSON.stringify({
    "uname": stdout
}));
```

This is effectively [what Express.js does when you call `res.send/res.json` on an object](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/ee228f7aea6448cf85cc052697f8d831dce785d5/lib/response.js#L174).

Comment: Thanks for the help! I never tried putting JSON.stringify there.

Comment: @AnttiKeränen: No problem! I think something key to bear in mind when working with Node's HTTP module is that it's a web *server* API, not a web *application* API. They don't implement higher level concerns like JSON, or authentication, etc. etc. etc. - they leave it up to you (or more likely, a framework like Express, Hapi or Restify) to decide how to implement those features in a way that fits your needs.